# Image Viewer auto slide codenamone

Tags: codenameone

How can i auto slide the imageViewer for instance in the interval of 3 seconds.
Or is there any other component that can do the auto swipe task.

```
ImageViewer imv = new ImageViewer();
DefaultListModel<Image> images = new DefaultListModel<Image>(new Image[]{a, thumbnail1, thumbnail2});
imv.setImage(images.getItemAt(0));
imv.setImageList(images);
imv.setSwipePlaceholder(Image.createImage(100, 100));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare this global static variable:

```
private static int slideIndex = 0;
//And this UITimer
UITimer t;
```

And then try out below code

```
final ImageViewer imv = new ImageViewer();
final DefaultListModel<Image> images = new DefaultListModel<Image>(new Image[]{a, thumbnail1, thumbnail2});
imv.setImage(images.getItemAt(0));
imv.setImageList(images);
imv.setSwipePlaceholder(Image.createImage(100, 100));

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (slideIndex < images.getSize()) {
            slideIndex++;
        } else {
            slideIndex = 0;
        }
        Image nextImage = (Image) images.getItemAt(slideIndex);
        if (nextImage != null) {
            imv.setImage(nextImage);
        }
    }
};
if (t == null) {
    t = new UITimer(r);
}
if (t != null) {
    t.schedule(3000, true, f); //3 seconds
}
```